# Unable to write to binary file using pickle Python

Tags: python, io, pickle, binaryfiles

So I'm having this problem where I'm trying to write a dictionary to a binary file and nothing happens. Very strange; no error message, nothing. It's like the program skips over the code, specifically this code

```
with open("database.dat", "wb") as handle:
        pickle.dump(d, handle)
        handle.close()
```

I have no problem loading from this database.dat file if it exists but this code doesn't seem to create a new binary file if it doesn't exist and it doesn't overwrite the file if it does exist. I've never had this problem so I'm perplexed...

To give an idea of where this fits in, this the function:

```
import pickle

def initialise_database(directory, file_name):

    try:
        with open("database.dat", "rb") as handle:
            d = pickle.load(handle) # THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
            handle.close()
            return d

    except FileNotFoundError:
        return update_database(directory, file_name)


def update_database(directory, file_name):
    import xlrd, os

    # Change directory
    os.chdir(directory)

    try:
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)

        sheet = wb.sheet_by_name("FUNDS")

        rows, cols = sheet.nrows, sheet.ncols

        d = {}
        for i in range(rows - 1):
            if sheet.cell_value(i + 1, 0) != "":
                charity = cap(sheet.cell_value(i + 1, 0))

                area_of_work = []
                org = []
                funding = 0

                for x in range(cols):
                    if sheet.cell_value(0, x) == "Area of work":
                        if sheet.cell_value(i + 1, x) != "":
                            area_of_work.append(cap(sheet.cell_value(i + 1, x)))
                        else:
                            pass

                    elif sheet.cell_value(0, x) == "Organisation funded":
                        if sheet.cell_value(i + 1, x) != "":
                            org.append(cap(sheet.cell_value(i + 1, x)))
                        else:
                            pass


                    elif sheet.cell_value(0, x) == "How much funding provided":
                        funding = (str_to_int(sheet.cell_value(i + 1, x)))

                        if funding is False:
                            print("\nCharity " + str(sheet.cell_value(i + 1, 0)) + ", number " + str(i + 2) + " has funding of value: "+ str(funding) + ", which is not compatible. Please find it and fix it in the the excel file. Then try again")
                            return False

                # Adds entry to dictionary
                d[charity] = [area_of_work, org, funding]

            else:
                pass

        # After the loop has finished, it should write the entire dictionary to a newly created file!

        with open("database.dat", "wb") as handle:
            pickle.dump(d, handle)
            handle.close()

        return d

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File could not be found.")
        print("Program terminating.\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

I've taken a look at other questions and none seem to touch on the problem I'm facing here. Any help on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I'd also like to add that when I run the code and perform

```
print(initialise_database( #my_directory, #my_file )
```

It does print out my database, meaning that the update() function is being called, seeing as there is no such database.dat file anywhere

As proof that the file is not appearing, here is a screenshot. This is after full_script (which is where this code is taken from) has been ran.

[image: Evidence there is no file]

Comment: Why do you close `handle`? The `with`takes care of that.

Comment: he has his return statement inside his with block. meaning it might not close, unless the with did close it.

Comment: @progmatico haha, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that. I'm still quite new to programming... I've taken it out but still no change :( idk why no binary file is being created. I double-checked all my directories and none have the file. Thus, it should create the file!

Comment: have you checked in the directory the python file is in?

Comment: I don't know if that's all your code, but the only code that runs in this snippet is the `import pickle`. I don't see any other top-level indented code.

Comment: @GeeTransit Doesn't directly relate to the question, but `with` guarantees that the file closes even if there is a `return` statement.

Comment: @progmatico there are a couple more functions being called in the code (namely cap and str_into_int) but I didn't bother including them because they didn't seem relevant and the code in the question is long enough as it is

Comment: @GeeTransit I made a (sub) directory specifically for program so it should be evident if (and when) the database.dat file is created. I've checked and there's no such file.

Comment: try `handle.flush()` in the end of with block

Comment: @progmatico I've tried handle.flush() and it didn't work :(

Comment: have you looked in the `directory` that you're `os.chdir`ing into?

Comment: @SamMason ooops, yeah it's in the directory that you've said. Specifically the directory is C:\Users\tomas_000\Documents. Is there any way to move the file to my pycharm directory? They normally appear there automatically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change:

```
# Change directory
os.chdir(directory)
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name)
```

to be:

```
import os.path

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(directory, file_name))
```

that way the "working directory" won't get changed, and your files will end up where you expect.

to explain a bit: whenever you [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) a file (this is what Python ends up calling, as would `xlrd` or any other native code). paths that don't start with a `/` (or `\` in Windows) are relative to your "current working directory" (CWD) or just working directory/folder.  your CWD will be inherited from the program that started your code (e.g. your shell or IDE) but you can change it programmatically as you were doing using `os.chdir`.

I generally stay away from changing directory as it tends to cause confusion (as you've experienced) and just use paths that get to the right place.  there are lots of better docs on the internet about this.  Microsoft has a document called [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file) that has all the gorey details and it's generally easier in Unix/Linux.  try searching for "relative vs absolute" path names, and finding out what `..` means.

Comment: I would hug you if I could... Do you mind explaining why the change matter? My knowledge of I/O is quite rudimentary and I would be very grateful if you could give some explanation to the solution

Comment: @Tom_G_99, it looks like your file was being created in a different folder. Your code has a "working folder", usually the one from where it is launched. With chdir you are changing it. When making I/O with relative paths or just a filename, this happens into the new changed working folder. With the solution given you don't change your working folder, so instead you have to open the files where they are, specifying a path for them.